# List of objects in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

If I have three objects of the same type, how can I add them in a list so I can do afterwards
`foreach ($entry in $list)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$a=1
$b=2
$c=3
$list = $a,$b,$c
```